# how to divide an array into different arrays in c++

Tags: c++

I have written this code in c++ to read a signal as an array and now I need to segment this array for 4 or 5 different arrays such that put first 20 elements in array1 ;20-50 in array2 and so on ..
how to do that in c++
my code :

```cpp
int main()
{
    // first we use for loop to insert the signal as arry by the user......
    int size;
    cout << "this programme read your signal as array first you need to "
            "determine the size of the array "
         << endl
         << " Enter desired size of the array";
    cin >> size;
    vector<float> sig(size);
    cout << "the signal  " << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        cin >> sig[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's quite a basic task, how do you think it could be done or what is stopping you from trying it? I ask because just giving you some code won't help you to learn the language.

Comment: what you want to do is often not necessary. For example standard algorithms work with iterators not containers, so you could keep all in one vector and still work on segments of it with different functions. On the other hand, you could read the input in several vectors already when reading input then you dont need to split the vector anymore

Comment: It's also a bit unclear how you want to divide the arrays. 0-19 in the first one, 20-49 in the next one: that's 20 and 30 elements. Should the next array be 40 elements? We can hardly extrapolate from just two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a `vector` with a subrange of another vector you can use the [constructor that takes two iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)( (5) in the link):

```
std::vector<float> x(100);
std::vector<flaot> y(x.begin()+begin,x.begin()+end);
```

`y` will have copies of elements from index `begin` till `end` (`end` not included) from `x`.

However, I would rather store the elements in the right place from the start instead of reading them into a `vector<float> sig(size);` first. Alternatively you can consider to keep all input in a single vector and pass iterators to functions that need to work with subranges of the full signal instead of splitting the signal.